# PayPal payments: Default to 'Pay with Credit Card' instead of loggin in with a PayPal Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have seen this done before so I know it's possible - when you redirect to a PayPal checkout from your site, paypal presents you with 2 options to make a payment. One is "Login with PayPal Account" and the other one is something like "Don't have a PayPal account? Pay with Credit/Debit Card". By default the second option is collapsed, but I've seen sites where it's uncollapsed by default. How can I achieve this effect?

NB - previous posts suggested that it's done by cookies, and if PayPal detects that you have a PayPal account it will display the first option (login with PayPal). However I've seen other sites that display the 'Credit/Debit' card option uncollapsed even if you've got a paypal account. Do they clear the cookies somehow before redirecting you to PayPal?

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

just add :)

```
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">
```

You are redirected to billing page...

Comment: This works for Paypal buttons, why isn't this the accepted answer?

Comment: Confirmed.  Works for me too.  Thanks!

Comment: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments-Archive/Guest-payement-is-not-available/td-p/807552?profile.language=en#M17338

Answer (score 9):

You can not set the credit card option to show by default if you are using Website Payments Standard.  This is set by cookies.  However, if you are using Express Checkout you can set the credit card section to show by default.  This is most likely what you have seen on other sites.  If you are using Express Checkout, and want to set this all you need to do is passing over the following 2 variables and values in your SetExpressCheckout API call.

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole

LANDINGPAGE=Billing
```

You also need to make sure you have PayPal account optional turned on in your PayPal account.  This is section is found in your profile.

Comment: On this note, when you set the options like this is displays the full credit card form by default with the PayPal option collapsed.  Is there any way to provide the Guest Checkout option here, but collapse both PayPal and CC options when they reach that page?

Comment: Currently there is not any parameters that can be set or passed over to do this.  However, I can pass this along to our development team as something to implement for future features.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the LANDINGPAGE parameter using the PayPal REST API?

Comment: This is incorrect. See answer below.  This is completely possible with web payments standard.

Answer (score 5):

A little bit late with this one but i recently had the same issue using Express Checkout JS

Managed to resolve this by adding the following to the js object

```
experience: {
  flow_config: {
     landing_page_type: "billing",
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the documentation for this.

Comment: documentation == > https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/customize-flow/#pass-web-experience-profile-options

Answer (score -2):

I came across from various sites regarding the same ask while I have workaround to achieve this for the time being. :) But your finding resolved my issue, that's cookies cause after I have my workaround applied.

The workaround to default the Paypal payment to Credit/Debit card option is to add the variables on your button such as country=COUNTRY_VALUE or any other variables you would think customer is fine to have it defaulted. Variables page https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0J0VU

Hope it helps you. :)